# Module not found for @material-ui/core/CheckBox when it is installed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, material-ui

My `@material-ui/core/CheckBox` module is not found when I tried to run `npm run build` [error when run npm run bhuild](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFSIK.png)

I checked manually in `node_modules/core/@material-ui/Checkbox and the package is there. However, npm is looking for the package outside of node_modules and hence having error trying to find it. [error installing package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORgUD.png). My node version is 16.0.0 and npm is 7.11.0.

I have tried delete node_modules folder and do `npm install` again multiple time but the same error exists. I tried to run the same setup in another ubuntu machine and it works, but not sure why it doesn't in this specific VM that I need it to run to host on the server.

Comment: I think you should try `npm install @material-ui/core` instead of `npm install @material-ui/core/CheckBox`

Comment: I also tried that, and it shows the successful installation. However, the error persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The checkbox must be imported correctly.

[image] **`import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';`**

[image] `import CheckBox from '@material-ui/core/CheckBox';`

Comment: I think my import is correct though because the same code works in another machine.

Comment: I just tried again and this actually fixes it. I don't know why the error wasn't showing in another machine.